# Why can't some CSS selectors style <input type="text">?

Tags: html, css

Say for example I have `<input type="text" class="class" id="id">`

if I use these selectors in style.css, they don't work:

```
input {text-align:center;}
.class {text-align:center;}
```

but when I use these selectors, they work:

```
input[type='text'] {text-align:center;}
input.class {text-align:center;}
#id {text-align:center;}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/7KRD9/6/

Could anyone explain why? I thought selectors target DOM elements.

Comment: learn about specificity http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/ you will get the answer.

Comment: The [all work](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/177a5fe1-9cd2-4d95-ba60-e082acbf9d90/5496aeab99e36c966ea3ac21fa65a1b2)

Comment: @Mr.Alien — It isn't technically zoomed in, it is some weird reaction between my screenshot tool and a retina display. I should get around to investigating that at some point.

Comment: @Quentin that was some real good quality image... would clean up the comments now.. :)

Comment: Yes Quentin, they all work, it was because of jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile that overrode the CSS. That was why it didn't work in my fiddle. I thought something was wrong with the CSS standards, or something was wrong with my common sense regarding CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fiddle, you have loaded jQuery UI, which adds some css. Because of that, your first two selectors are overridden by this css, but the last ones are more specific than the ones given by jQuery UI, so they are considered more important.

Comment: This is the correct answer. They all work correctly now.

Comment: @Geoyws than what did I wrote? *all the selectors should work the way they are*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with CSS [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

It is basically a system of assigning "weights" to different CSS selectors, in order to determine which one will be applied.

For example, an #id selector is more specific(has more weight) than a .class selector. So if you have two selectors on your page like so:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
.mylinks { ... }
#mylink { text-decoration: underline; }
```

The latter will win because the #mylink selector has a higher specificity than the former.

If you want your styles to be applied correctly, use the more specific seletors.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the specification in cs

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fool/7KRD9/7/) you can see, with "Important" it will work.
Some more information about this is [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

```
/* This doesn't work.*/
input {
    text-align:center;
    background:lime!Important;
}

/* This doesn't work.*/
.class {
    text-align:center;
    background:red!Important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand,why this simple thing not working with you?
here hava a look at this

**html**

```
<input type="text" value="this is demo"/>
```

**css**

```
input
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

**/* This doesn't work.*/**

```
.class {
    text-align:center;
    background:red!Important;
}
```

here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TK4Z6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with the jsfiddle and I think it's about CSS specificity calculation, here is en article about that on CSS-tricks: [css specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

This is more of a complement to Mr. Alien's answer.